# Can anyone out there help me for Zoom RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, zooming, android-relativelayout

Actually I want to create RelativeLayout with data represent in a excel structure. So I want to zoom that data .I research a lot. but could not find a right way to zoom relativelayout. can any one please help me to find out this solution , so  I have zoom relativeLayout. My main aim is to zoom data. so any container that supports to zoom , I will take.

I had also try webview. but in 4.0.4 and 4.0.3 while data is refresh . our zoom function reset its original position..

Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may help you a while,.. refer here http://myandroidnote.blogspot.in/2011/03/zooming-view-completely.html